# Draw only positively weighted edge NetworkX

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I am looking for a clean, easy way to draw a weighted NetworkX graph with only its positively weighted edges.

The only way I can think of is this:

```
pos=nx.spring_layout(G) 
# filter and only draw positive edges
positive_edges = [(u,v) for (u,v,d) in G.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] >0]
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edgelist=positive_edges)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

I wonder if there is an easier way. I imagine something like this:

```
nx.draw(G, only_positive_edge=True)
```

or

```
nx.draw(G, zero_weighted_edge_invisible=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can extract the edges into a numpy array and then apply the filter.
You can use [to_numpy_matrix](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.7/reference/generated/networkx.convert.to_numpy_matrix.html) to change edge list to numpy array and apply numpy filter, which are quite performance wise for large graphs as compare to conventional for loops, etc. Then once the modification is done use [from_numpy_matrix](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.7/reference/generated/networkx.convert.from_numpy_matrix.html) to get the graph into networkx format.
    import networkx as nx
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    G = nx.Graph()

```
#Add Nodes
G.add_node(1)
G.add_node(2)
G.add_node(3)
G.add_node(4)

#Add edges
G.add_edge(1, 2, weight= -1)
G.add_edge(2, 3, weight= 1)
G.add_edge(1, 3, weight= 2)
G.add_edge(4, 3, weight= -1)

#Extract edges into numpy array 
edges =  nx.to_numpy_matrix(G, nodelist= G.nodes())

#Change non-negative values to 0 
edges[edges<0] = 0

#Save the modified graph
G2 = nx.from_numpy_matrix(edges)

pos=nx.spring_layout(G2)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G2,pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G2,pos)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]